# Failed to deploy Webservice into weblogic server

Tags: web-services, oracle, deployment, weblogic

I developed webservice and I want to deploy it into weblogic, so that I can integrate it with my portal application.
My webservice works well in integrated Weblogic server(10.3.5). But, when I try to deploy it into development server (10.3.6), Weblogic throw an exception. 
I also try to deploy it into EAR file, and I got the same exception.

The error message is :
[02:16:01 PM] Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.bind.AccessorFactoryImpl cannot be cast to com.sun.xml.bind.InternalAccessorFactory

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? I'm still trying to deploy it into 10.3.6 version.

Answer (score 0):

Please check versions in web.xml.

WebApp_ID version should be as javaee version you specified.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstall the weblogic server using jrockit 1.6.0_33 then I able to deploy my webservice. Means that I downgrade jdk (not latest version).